# Order emails not being sent

Tags: php, email

I am trying to customize the Fooman Email PDF module, so the PDF will only be added if the order contains at least one virtual product.
I have been working in Observer.php where I added a single line of code to the original file, but after adding it the order emails are not being sent. I therefore need help revise the code or how else it can be achieved.

The original code
[image]

The customized code
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try debugging by logging the value of $order->getQuote()->geVirtualItemsQty() like this
Mage::log($order->getQuote()->geVirtualItemsQty(), null, 'orderemails.log')
Add this line of code before the if condition. This will help you to identify whether its returning value greater than zero or not, in case of Virtual products in order. If not you then have to change your approach.

Good Luck!:)